# Получить ассемблерный исходник из файла с++/c в MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, c, mingw

можно ли получить код ассемблера в стиле интел из исходника с/с++ в MinGW или MinGw-w64? использовал ключ -S но он выдает в стиле AT&T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно добавить флаг `-masm=intel`.